# Image path not found

Tags: c#, image, email, email-attachments

How can i add an image to an email message sent from a web server in C#

this is the code i am using:

```
        string emailType = "NewMember";
        string sMessage = GetData.emailText(emailType);
        string sEmail = GetData.userEmails(userName);
        string sSubject = GetData.emailSubject(emailType);
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        string htmlBody = "<html><body>Dear " + userName + sMessage + "<br/><br/><img src=\"cid:filename\"></body></html>";
        AlternateView avHtml = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString
           (htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);

        LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
        inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        avHtml.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.AlternateViews.Add(avHtml);

        Attachment att = new Attachment("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg");
        att.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
        MailAddress sFrom = new MailAddress("info@website.com");
        MailAddress sTo = new MailAddress(sEmail);
        mail.From = sFrom;
        mail.To.Add(sTo);
        mail.Subject = sSubject;
        mail.Body = String.Format(
                   htmlBody +
                   @"<img src=""cid:{0}"" />", inline.ContentId);

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mail.Attachments.Add(att);
        smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

`
this is the error message i am getting:
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\~\Resources\images\logo.jpg

Comment: Is the image held within your application?

Comment: It may also be worth you defining the path explicitly rather than implicitly - just to rule out incorrect directory path. Edit -  Failing that switch out the cid in the img tag and point it to a server that's accessible by the recepients.

Comment: 1.You need to add a virtual path to the image. (For Example:  

h ttp://YourDomain/YourWebProjectRoot/Resources/images/logo.jpg'

2.The image needs to be available on a public facing webserver for the clients your sending the email to; To be able to view the image when they read their email.

Comment: Yes, the image is within the asp application in the folder 'images'

Comment: This code now runs without errors but the image is attached as an ext file instead of a jpg file, it opens with ms paint as the correct image so the path is correct. How can i send the image in the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg"));
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource(Server.MapPath("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg"), MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

Instead of -

```
Attachment att = new Attachment("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg");
LinkedResource inline = new LinkedResource("~/Resources/images/logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

Because you need the path of the resource that is inside website folder. So you have to map path with `Server.MapPath`. More details here -

[Server.MapPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I have changed the path using Server.Map path and the code now runs and send the message with an attachment but it is a .ext file not a jpg file and does not display in the message body. How can i send the logo.jpg image in the correct format?  Cheers, Andy

Comment: Not sure whats wrong, but it sounds like it is not understanding the file format and may be tried to scan it with antivirus, try mentioning `ContentDisposition` as mentioned here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've managed to get the file attachement to work but the Image does not display in the message body, just a place holder. 'FileStream fileToStream = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/logo.jpg"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Attachment att = new Attachment(fileToStream, "Logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);'

Comment: @user3746002 Do you mean to have the image as part of the email body? If so, you can have something like: string htmlBody = "<html><body>Dear " + userName + sMessage + "<br/><br/><img src=\"" + filepath + "\"></body></html>";

Comment: I have resolved this now with:
       
            string sImage = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/logo.jpg");
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); 
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            
            FileStream fileToStream = new 
                FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/images/logo.jpg"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            Attachment att = new Attachment(fileToStream, "Logo.jpg", MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);